# How to rename file and folder of mp3 based on ID3 tag

Tags: rename, id3

How to rename music files based on ID3 tag with format: `number. title` where the number doesn't exists on the id3tag but exists on the file name?

And how to rename folders based on ID3 tag with format `artist - album`?

I've tried [id3ren](https://github.com/sebcode/id3ren) but it gives underscore output for non-ascii characters.

Example input:

```
???? ????/01. ????.mp3
???? ????/02. ???????.mp3
```

Example output:

```
[Artist] - [Album]/01. [Title].mp3
[Artist] - [Album]/02. [Title].mp3
```

Where the `[label]` are from ID3 tag

Comment: I think Id3ren can understands ascii, but also you use a terminal that doesn't support utf-8, check it.

Comment: no, my terminal has been set to `utf-8` since installation..